# sms using adb shell not working

Tags: adb

I am trying to send the sms by both adb shell am and adb shell service call .I am getting error for both .
a)I am trying to send the sms following adb shell am command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:"phoneNumber" --es   sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exi
t_on_sent true adb adb shell input keyevent 66
```

and I am getting error-

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxxx pkg=BODY (has extras) }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x1000
0000 pkg=BODY (has extras) }
```

b) when sending by service cell

```
adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "phonenumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"
```

Result-

```
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: ffffffff 00000061 006f0043 00790070 '....a...C.o.p.y.'
  0x00000010: 006e0069 00200067 0065006d 00730073 'i.n.g. .m.e.s.s.'
  0x00000020: 00670061 00200065 006f0074 00490020 'a.g.e. .t.o. .I.'
  0x00000030: 00630063 0020003a 0065004e 00740069 'c.c.:. .N.e.i.t.'
  0x00000040: 00650068 00200072 00730075 00720065 'h.e.r. .u.s.e.r.'
  0x00000050: 00320020 00300030 00200030 006f006e ' .2.0.0.0. .n.o.'
  0x00000060: 00200072 00750063 00720072 006e0065 'r. .c.u.r.r.e.n.'
  0x00000070: 00200074 00720070 0063006f 00730065 't. .p.r.o.c.e.s.'
  0x00000080: 00200073 00610068 00200073 006e0061 's. .h.a.s. .a.n.'
  0x00000090: 00720064 0069006f 002e0064 00650070 'd.r.o.i.d...p.e.'
  0x000000a0: 006d0072 00730069 00690073 006e006f 'r.m.i.s.s.i.o.n.'
  0x000000b0: 0052002e 00430045 00490045 00450056 '..R.E.C.E.I.V.E.'
  0x000000c0: 0053005f 0053004d 0000002e          '_.S.M.S.....    ')
```

but there is no sms on my device.

Please help me figure out What is missing in both the cases.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe there is an issue with the number. Try without quotes.
Have you tried this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:+1-222-333-4444
adb shell input text "sampletexthere"
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Comment: is this enough to see the message in the message app as well?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
you have to escape your spaces in your message body. use \

"message\ body\ goes\ here"